# Call a method of MasterViewController on DetailViewController

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm making a small iPad APP using the `SplitViewController` and I want to call a method from the `MasterViewController` on the `DetailViewController` but the method doesn't show up when I write the following code to call it:

```
MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
[master pushModuleTitle];
```

Here is my method in `MasterViewController.m`

```
-(void)pushModuleTitle:(NSString*)moduleTitile
{
    NSString * moduleTitileObject = moduleTitile;
    [self.moduleTitleStack addObject:moduleTitileObject];
}
```

Not sure why I am getting this issue! This is how you call e method right?

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
   -(void)pushModuleTitle:(double)moduleTitile
```

takes one parameter, but you are calling it with no parameters. No function exists that takes zero parameters! You either need to change your call to

```
  [master pushModuleTitle:5.0]; // for example
```

or add

```
  -(void)pushModuleTitle
```

Comment: but pushModelTitle does not even show up when I start entering the name, its like it doesn't exist. p.s i have changed my method

Comment: Make sure you have included the definition of the function in MasterViewController.h

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating a *new* MasterViewController instance instead of *referencing* the existing instance.

What you need to do is access the SplitViewController instance and ask for objectAtIndex:0 (left side). This object is what you're looking for.

```
//in detailView.m



//accesses the splitViewController property on the viewController class. User @rdelmar clarified that iOS sets this property automatically

UISplitViewController *split = self.splitViewController; 
//UISplitViewController will return an array if you access the viewControllers property. Ask the array for the first object. This object is the left hand object.
MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController *)[split.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[master pushModuleTitle:@"Master"];
```

Edit: Further explanation

In Object Oriented Languages like Objective-C, we have a term called "Encapsulation". An object doesn't know about other objects by design. By using the object's *interface* (the .h or header file) other objects can learn what messages they can send to your object. If you follow the answer above you can see the path you take to get from one object to the next:

1. Ask the ViewController for it's `splitViewController` property (UISplitViewController)
2. Ask the splitViewController for it's `viewControllers` property (NSArray)
3. Ask the viewControllers array to give you `objectAtIndex:0` (returns left side of splitView)

Comment: What do u mean by this libe UISplitViewController *split = delegate.splitViewController; (isn't there a simpler way to call a method from another class

Comment: You don't need to access anything in the app delegate. The detail view controller has a property self.splitViewController that references the split view controller it's embedded in. To get the master, just use self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0]

Comment: @rdelmar this is not necessarily true. If he is using the "stock" UISplitView project in XCode, the detailViewController does have that property. I guess this is much like my assumption that his appDelegate is set up correctly. But detailViewController is not a UIKit construct, it's just a viewController class inside the UISplitView at index:1. It would only have a splitView reference if one was set up and assigned.

Comment: @JustinAmberson, no, that's not true. UIViewController has a splitViewController property, and it will be non-nil if the controller is embedded in a split view controller. You don't have to do anything to set it up.

Comment: @user2382834 sadly, there is not a "simpler" way to do this. But, this is actually the "easy" way and when you understand how and why it works this way, you'll appreciate it more. A convoluted way would be to use the NSNotificationCenter (don't ask). It's hard to explain, but objects in an object oriented language don't know about other arbitrary objects within the program. What my answer is showing you is how to use one object (the AppDelegate object) to find the reference to another object (SplitView) which has another object (array of viewControllers) to find the masterView (final object)

Comment: @rdelmar I stand corrected, thanks for the clarification, I'll edit my answer